# How to have test execution skipped based on some condition (let's say environment variable) using AVA framework

Tags: javascript, testing, skip, ava

I need to skip some tests base on the condition. Due to the current framework setup the best possibility would be to use environment variable.
Something like

```
test.before(() => {if(skipAll==true) skipAllTests();})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you could put the `test()` calls in an `if` condition?

Comment: Thank you @MarkWubben.
Yep, exactly what I just did. Makes code a bit ugly. I think adding `skipIf()` would be better approach.

Comment: Maybe you could [file an issue](https://github.com/avajs/ava) with that suggestion, and more details on what conditions you are using, and why you can't split up your test files instead?